# Merge words with hyphenation and line breaks (regex)

Tags: regex, string, notepad++, line-breaks, hyphenation

When a hyphenated word is separated by a line break, I want to merge them. So the condition is that a hyphen is followed by a line break. If a hyphen is followed by a whitespace, nothing at all should happen.

This is to be merged because a line break follows:

```
This is a ice-
cream and this is a car
```

And in such examples, nothing at all should be merged because the line is clean.

```
This is a ice-cream and this is a car
```

How can I do this with regular expressions (I use Notepad++)?

If I use the following regular expression, then everything is just merged.

- Search for: `[^\s-]\K-\s+(?=[^\s-]) ()`
- Replace with: nothing

Comment: Maybe `-\r\n` and replace it with nothing?

Comment: Replace `(\S)-\R(\S)` with `$1-$2`

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=-)\n` and replace with nothing ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hhT9JR/1)).

This is called a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**Find what**

```
[^\s-]-\K\R(?=[^\s-])
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\s-]` a non whitespace char other than `-`
- `-\K` Match `-` and forget what is matched so far
- `\R` Match any any unicode newline sequence
- `(?=[^\s-])` Assert a non whitespace char other than `-` to the right

**Replace with**

Leave empty

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xUAwmw/1).

[image]